# Rabbitmq mirrored queue performance

Tags: amazon-ec2, scalability, message-queue, rabbitmq, middleware

I am going to user rabbitmq cluster for my web app. As I am implementing auto scaling using AutoScaling service of AWS, I am planning to use mirrored queue. I have read [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) article of rabbitmq mirrored queue. Taking performance as a consideration I would like to know that will it be recommended to implement mirrored queue in rabbtimq cluster? i.e. will the performance decrease compared with non-persistent queue?

I haven't found any good articles of benchmark with mirrored queue. Can anybody share their suggestion?

Comment: Yes, performance will degrade, but I have no idea by how much.  Ultimately, each use case is different, so you'll need to write your own benchmark to check for your case.  If you need some pointers, send a message to the RabbitMQ Discuss mailing list; the developers make a point of answering all questions posted there.  There would also be other people there who'd have tried HA queues.